# How do I print the term names associated with a node?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I want to show the term names used in a node. My term field machine name is field_category.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'content_type');
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($entity_ids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   dpm($node);
}
```

`dpm()` prints the following.

```
stdClass Object(
[__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
[in_preview] => 
[values] => Array
 [field_category] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 4
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )
```

How can I print the term names as *term-1,term-2*?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $categories = $node->field_category->referencedEntities();
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    print_r($category->getName(). ",");
  }
  print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Using the field items is IMHO simpler: foreach ($node->field_category as $item) { print $item->entity->getName(); }. Don't forget an if ($item->entity) check however, as it is possible that you have a dead reference.